# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot recognize monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, display

The attached image shows that Ubuntu cannot recognize my display, and there is only one resolution to choose.

[image: Screen capture of Settings-Displays]

Monitor: LG 38CB99 3840*1600
Graphic card: RTX 2080ti

I tried to install the Nvidia-390 driver following the instructions and restarted, but this problem persists.

I am a beginner of Linux, and I need a more comfortable screen presentation to proceed learning. Could you help solve my problem?

`xrandr` result:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

When I run `lspci`:

```
lspci -k | grep -iEA5 'vga|display|3d'
```

Result:

```
43:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e04 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3711
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
43:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f7 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3711
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try another cable and see the result
2. post `xrandr` results
3. It may also be some problem with kernel or driver. Or maybe monitor's EDID is broken (so you need to use workaround)

Workaround:
`xrandr` should tell you there is a virtual display `VIRTUAL1 disconnected` or something.

```
xrandr --newmode NEWMODE_NAME $(cvt <WIDTH> <HEIGHT>|tail -n 1|awk '{$1="" ;$2="";print $0}')
xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 NEWMODE_NAME
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --mode NEWMODE_NAME
xrandr --addmode <YOUR OUTPUT JACK> NEWMODE_NAME
xrandr --output <YOUR OUTPUT JACK> --mode NEWMODE_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you for response.

1. I am using DP; however, HDMI does not give any signal. DP works very well in Win10. I installed dual OS.
2. xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*

The first line of your additional command gives:
bash: command substitution: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
bash: command substitution: line 10: `cvt <WIDTH> <HEIGHT>|tail -n 1|awk '{$1="" ;$2="";print $0}')'

Any new suggestion, please?

Comment: @AndrewSHI WIDTH and HEIGHT you need to give resolusion

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. It is quite easy.

Just download the .run file from Nvidia website and install it:

```
sudo chmod +x /downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.78.run
sudo /downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.78.run
```

The interface is more friendly than Linux portal, and you do not have to type commands.

After finishing, restart. Everything will be all right!

xrandr result:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1600, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 3840x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 874mm x 366mm
3840x1600     59.99*+  75.00    29.99  
3440x1440     75.05    59.97  
2560x1080     59.94    50.00  
1920x1080     74.91    60.00    59.94    50.00  
1680x1050     59.95  
1600x900      60.00  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1280x800      59.81  
1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
1152x864      59.96  
1024x768      75.03    60.00  
800x600       75.00    60.32  
720x576       50.00  
720x480       59.94  
640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
USB-C-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```